# Accessing a single resource for multi-user environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, resources, real-time, threadpool

I am working on a application which is almost near to realtime application, there will me more than 100 users connected to this application.

Now my problem is that i am having a binary resource i.e. a mp3 file. I am creating a separate user instance for each user, and the application works fine, but problem is that the file is of more than 5MB, so if i create separate instance for 100 users, the size will be 500MB and so it continuously consumes memory.

The another solution which i am thinking on is that to keep this resource as global(static), but as this is a multi-user environment application and all users will be accessing the resource continuously, i think there may be problem if i keep this resource global for all user.

What do you suggest? Plz share if you have any other idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you write the resource or is it read-only? You might also consider a middle-ground with, say, 10 copies shared by 10 users each.

Comment: If the users are only reading the file, can you reference count the loaded file object, (lock the count or use atomics)?

Comment: thanks for the reply... the resource is readonly

Answer (score 0):

A tradeoff is required when it comes to performance and memory usage.

If the same binary resources are being provided to all users, it is better to keep it global (assuming that there are no access controls present for a user to access a resource). But instead of storing all the binary resources continuously in the memory, a mechanism for caching the resources can be done.

When a user is accessing a particular resource for the first time, it can be loaded into the memory. If it is not being accessed by any users after a configured interval, it can be removed from the memory.